# indexedDB Creating a database and adding content Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase'

Tags: javascript, local, indexeddb, persistent-object-store

This is the first time for me to use indexDB, I've created a database and now trying to add content to it. But I'm getting the following error.

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.

I've uploaded my code on jsfiddle just because its easier to show you it running. Any suggestions please ?

https://jsfiddle.net/8kj43kyn/

```
// Creating an indexDB - Used to store users information.  
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || 
window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Should that

```
var transaction = db.transaction( ["books", 'readwrite']);
```

be

```
var transaction = db.transaction(["books"], 'readwrite');
```

Comment: Note that once you've made this change and in order to re-test, you need to open a new tab on your browser. It's not enough to simply refresh. No idea why